# using this in JavaScript module

Tags: javascript, module, this, strict-mode

I wrote the following code (mock up) :

```js
module.exports = {
    test() {
        console.log('test')
    },
    iffer(nb) {
        if (nb !== 0) {
            this.test()
        }
    }
}
```

I got the error "test is not a function".

And tried the following :

```js
let that = this
module.exports = {
    test() {
        console.log('test')
    },
    iffer(nb) {
        if (nb !== 0) {
            that.test()
        }
    }
}
```

This solution still doesn't works as JavaScript modules have strict mode on by default. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Please show us how you are calling `iffer()`

Comment: I'm calling iffer() from another file lie this my Modules. iffer(5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reference `module.exports` again.

```
iffer(nb){
    if (nb !== 0) {
        module.exports.test()
    }
}
```

You could also put the exported object into a standalone variable first to make it easier to reference. Or, have *all* functions be standalone for easy reference, then export an object with all of them.

```
const test = () => console.log('test');
const iffer = (nb) => {
    if (nb !== 0) {
        test();
    }
};
module.exports = { test, iffer };
```

If your environment is compatible with ES6 module syntax, I'd recommend using them instead.

```
export const test = () => console.log('test');
export const iffer = (nb) => {
    if (nb !== 0) {
        test();
    }
};
```